# Center Align Title Google Chart

Tags: javascript, api, charts, center

How can I center the title in a Line Chart from Google Charts API  (Not Google Chart Images)

I don't see any options like titlePosition: 'center'

Thanks!

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['xValues', 'yValues'],
    [0, 34.92],
    [389, 39.44],
    [488, 52.11],
    [652, 55.4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    curveType: 'none', // 'function'
    title: 'Title',
    titleTextStyle: {
      color: '333333',
      fontName: 'Arial',
      fontSize: 10
    },
    legend: 'none',
    enableInteractivity: false
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

​

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Charts: Pie Chart title position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282210/google-charts-pie-chart-title-position)

Comment: This seems a sensible workaround: [Center align title in Google Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399041/2943403)

Answer (score 20):

This option is not provided by [the API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options); you simply cannot do this.

Answer (score 11):

I use:
titlePosition: 'none'

And insert a title with normal HTML

Answer (score 4):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16291236/364) suggests something like the following:

```
$("text:contains(" + vencOptions.title + ")").attr({'x':'60', 'y':'20'})
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16291236/364

Answer (score 2):

```
$("text:contains(" + vencOptions.title + ")").attr({'x':'60', 'y':'20'})
```

//OR

```
$("#YOUR_GRAPH_WRAPPER svg text").first().attr("x", (($("#time-series-graph svg").width() - parseInt($("#YOUR_GRAPH_WRAPPER svg text").first().attr('x'),10)) / 2).toFixed(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

After drawing the chart, call the event handler function:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', Title_center);
```

And define the function as:

```
function Title_center(){

     var title_chart=$("#payer_chart_div svg g").find('text').html();   

     $("#payer_chart_div svg").find('g:first').html('<text text-anchor="start" x="500" y="141" font-family="Arial" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">'+title_chart+'</text>');
}
```

Just insert the title of your chart and add the attributes `X:500`,`y:141`.

Comment: But not is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the callback info from the chart after it has been drawn and a bit of math working on some text in a div.

Contain your chart in a position:relative div.  Add a div under the chart and position both it and the chart absolute.

Then you can move the div's top & left positions with a little high-school math.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/o6zmbLvk/2/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#YOUR_GRAPH_WRAPPER svg text").first()
   .attr("x", (($("#time-series-graph svg").width() - $("#YOUR_GRAPH_WRAPPER svg text").first().width()) / 2).toFixed(0));
```

[See my explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282210/google-charts-pie-chart-title-position#answer-37955343)

Answer (score 0):

To show chart title in center of chart use below code snippet; it will dynamically set title in center of chart container.

Add `ready` event listener; `google.visualization.events.addListener(myChart, 'ready', titleCenter);` and add function `titleCenter`.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

var options = {
  title: "Chart Title",
  titleTextStyle: {
      bold: true,
      italic: true,
      fontSize: 18,
  },
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
  legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
  bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
  isStacked: true,
};

function drawAxisTickColors() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
       'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
      ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
      ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
      ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
    ]);
    
    var myChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(myChart, 'ready', titleCenter);
    myChart.draw(data, options);
}

function titleCenter() {
    var $container = $('#chart_div');
    var svgWidth = $container.find('svg').width();
    var $titleElem = $container.find("text:contains(" + options.title + ")");
    var titleWidth = $titleElem.html().length * ($titleElem.attr('font-size')/2);
    var xAxisAlign = (svgWidth - titleWidth)/2;
    $titleElem.attr('x', xAxisAlign);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: how can we use same title alighnment on multiple charts

Answer (score 0):

```
function Title_center(total) {
    var title_chart = $("#chart svg g").find('text').html();
    var x = $("#chart svg g").find('rect').attr('width');
    var y = $("#chart svg g").find('rect').attr('y');
    alert(x);
    $("#chart svg").find('g:first')
                   .html('<text text-anchor="start" x="'+x/2+'" y="'+y+'" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">' + total + '</text>');
}
```

Create this fuction in script, and call after chart draw like:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', Title_center("Test success"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As previous answer said, you can´t config a centered title. Just don´t set any "title" config. By defult it will not be displayed.

Then you can set a title with HTML, some code:

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">Some Centered Title</div>
    <div id="chart_container">
        <!-- THE CHART GOES HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Center chart tile
- Dynamically adjust to title length
- Overlaps with title from *google.visualization.LineChart* (not tested with other types of charts)

All this in 1 CSS class and 4 lines of JavaScript.

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64501781/4157871)

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById('divid').getElementsByTagName('text')[0].setAttribute('x', '350')

Comment: Hi Daniel, are you able to add any supporting text to this answer? Explaining why that works and perhaps linking to the supporting API documents.

Comment: Please provide some description of what your code does.

Answer (score -2):

```
svg > g:first-of-type > text {
    transform: translateX(calc(50% - 150px));
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation about what your code does and why you suggest it.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.