# Title and legend alignment?

Tags: angularjs, text-alignment, google-pie-chart

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zh1g5305/13/

I am new to google charts and `angularjs`, in above example in jsfiddle you can see the title in right side and legend in left. How can I move this to the top of pie chart also title and legends should be vertically aligned.
any suggestions are welcome.thanks

Comment: Your fiddle, wasn't working. Here's [updated one](https://jsfiddle.net/zh1g5305/13/)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16291236/4573999) may help