# Center align title in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

How can I center align the chart title in a Google Charts chart?

I don't see any options for positioning the title.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Period", "Daily"],
    ['a', 3],
    ['b', 3],
    ['c', 1]
]);

var options = {
    title:"number of publications",
    titleFontSize:30,
    width: 1100, height: 600,
    legend: { position: "none" }
}

// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("daily")).
draw(data, options);
```

Comment: I never worked with Google Charts API before, does it have any .css files? If yes, if you provide your html and css file maybe I can help you to set title alignment through css.

Answer (score 17):

What I would do is remove the title from the chart and add a header above the chart which would allow you to center it using CSS.

Add header to page:

```
<h2 class="piechartheader">Pie Chart Header</h2>
```

To remove the title from the chart use `titlePosition: 'none'`.

```
var options = {
  width: 1100,
  height: 600,
  titlePosition: 'none',
  legend: {
    position: "none"
  }
}
```

For more info: [Google Chart Documentation - Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Configuration_Options).

Comment: Agree, there is no other option to centre the title. You can only remove it. The simple way to remove title from the graph would be simply remove "title:" from options.

Comment: In my case, after setting titlePosition to 'none', title is not displayed and big margin at top is present.. is there a way to hide title and let other components of chart automatically fill this space?

Comment: missing comma after second option

Answer (score 2):

I am using Google pie chart. I searched for the text element where the title sits and changed its position using the following code:

You can do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#YourChartID > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > svg > g:nth-child(3) > text').setAttribute("x", 100);
```

You can play with the value of X (100 in my example) in order to drag the title to the left or to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, together with variable chart title length for the same chart, the [Tall Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55833213/4157871) solution, although simple, wouldn't solve it.

So, also considering the [Joe P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399041/4157871) answer, I've created an automatic solution that overlaps perfectly with the title from *google.visualization.LineChart* (not tested with other types of charts, but could also work).

The code:

```
    // Insert your chart code here...
    const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(dataDivElement);
    chart.draw(dataTable, options); // Drawing chart

    // After chart is drawn, add chart title
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.className = 'googleChartTitle';
    node.innerHTML = 'Chart Title';

    // Insert the node inside the chart divs
    dataDivElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].append(node);
```

The CSS:

```
.googleChartTitle {
    font: bold 11px Arial;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```