How to put main title of google column chart in the center?
Here's my basic code to draw column chart using Google Charts API:
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Google Charts</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
    var my_chart = document.getElementById("my_chart");

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Marks'],
        ['Sachin', 85],
        ['Amit', 60],
        ['Rohit', 75],
        ['Deepak', 50],
        ['Rahul', 55]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: "Students Marks",
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: "red",
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: false,
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(my_chart);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#my_chart {
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;     
}
</style>

<div id="my_chart"></div>

I need to place main title of chart (Students Marks) in the center of chart. I can't see any option in official docs.
I tried a couple of options like titleTextPosition and titlePosition myself to test whether they work or not but they don't.
Does anybody know how to do that?

this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64501781/6796856

@MicheleDeFalco No, that didn't work.

if you follow the instructions carefully it works, for me it worked, you have to replace dataDivElement with your own my_chart

Here is your working code, instead of using titleTextStyle, put your css rules in the .googleChartTitle


google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
    var my_chart = document.getElementById("my_chart");

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Marks'],
        ['Sachin', 85],
        ['Amit', 60],
        ['Rohit', 75],
        ['Deepak', 50],
        ['Rahul', 55]
    ]);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(my_chart);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  
   const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.className = 'googleChartTitle';
    node.innerHTML = 'Students Marks';

    // Insert the node inside the chart divs
    my_chart.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].append(node);
}
#my_chart {
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;     
}

.googleChartTitle {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="my_chart"></div>



